# Toggle Button Control

Tags: vb.net

Can I change my button control to toggle-button?

Is there any simple way to change the button property to make it toggle button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=797) on OSIX all you need to do is use a `CheckBox` but set it's appearance to `Button`.

In code:

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
checkBox1.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

(C# code but you see how it works).

But you can do this from the Properties dialog in the designer.

Comment: This works, I just put a checkbox, set its appearance to Button and this works like a toggle button, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

**To Change Checkbox to Simple Latching On/Off Button**

[image]

```
myCheckBox.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button
```

---

**To Add Custom Toggle (Sliding) On/Off Switch**

[image]

1. Right click project in VS and select 'Add' then 'User Control...'

   [image]
2. Name your new file "Toggle.vb"
3. Paste the code below
4. Switch to your form and drag your 'toggle' control from toolbox to form
   [image]
5. Size & settings can be changed like standard control
6. Colors can be changed in `OnPaint` method of Toggle Class

---

**VB.net**

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Toggle
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    Private _checked As Boolean
    Public Property Checked As Boolean
        Get
            Return _checked
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            If Not _checked.Equals(value) Then
                _checked = value
                Me.OnCheckedChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Sub OnCheckedChanged()
        RaiseEvent CheckedChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Event CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseClick(e As MouseEventArgs)
        Me.Checked = Not Me.Checked
        Me.Invalidate()
        MyBase.OnMouseClick(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Me.OnPaintBackground(e)
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

        Using path = New GraphicsPath()
            Dim d = Padding.All
            Dim r = Me.Height - 2 * d
            path.AddArc(d, d, r, r, 90, 180)
            path.AddArc(Me.Width - r - d, d, r, r, -90, 180)
            path.CloseFigure()
            e.Graphics.FillPath(If(Checked, Brushes.DarkGray, Brushes.LightGray), path)
            r = Height - 1
            Dim rect = If(Checked, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(Width - r - 1, 0, r, r), New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, r, r))
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(If(Checked, Brushes.Green, Brushes.LightSlateGray), rect)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**C#**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Your_Project_Name
{
    class Toggle : CheckBox
    {
        public Toggle()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            Padding = new Padding(6);
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnPaintBackground(e);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                var d = Padding.All;
                var r = this.Height - 2 * d;
                path.AddArc(d, d, r, r, 90, 180);
                path.AddArc(this.Width - r - d, d, r, r, -90, 180);
                path.CloseFigure();
                e.Graphics.FillPath(Checked ? Brushes.DarkGray : Brushes.LightGray, path);
                r = Height - 1;
                var rect = Checked ? new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Width - r - 1, 0, r, r)
                                    : new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, r, r);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Checked ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.LightSlateGray, rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*This code is from several sources over the years and has some minor tweaks.  It appears it exist in various forms on different sites so it's unclear who to attribute*

*All code was tested in Visual Studio 2017*

Comment: @Automate it's work's fine if the user clicks the toggle. But using `.Checked = True` does set the toggle to checked = true though it's not visually updated. Can you point out how to over come this? I am not an expert (obviously) and things I have tried do not help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I broke any rules by doing so. But changed the following: `Set(value As Boolean)
            _checked = value
            OnCheckedChanged()
            Invalidate()

            ''original
            'If Not _checked.Equals(value) Then
            '    _checked = value
            '    OnCheckedChanged()
            'End If
        End Set` And this worked. Would appreciate feedback on how to properly do this if my attempt was improper. Thanks

Comment: @Philippe - Good question... looking back I don't think I've ever needed to set it from code so I haven't seen this issue.  I typically add it from the toolbar and then set the default in the properties window.  I'm assuming you need this because you are resetting or generating the button from code.  I see nothing wrong with your approach but I'm no expert either. If you uncover any more info feel free to edit the post or let me know and I will.  cheers

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you can achieve this functionality by using a flag. For example:
bool isClicked = false;

and in the clicked event to put the following code to invert the bool:
isClicked = !isClicked;